# Вывести objectList з MySQL согласно порядку массива в where

Tags: php, mysql

Беру ряд строк с таблицы MySQL:

```
$IDs = array(5,3,1,4,2);
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id','introtext')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('id')." IN (".implode(',', $IDs).")");
$db->setQuery($query);
$articles = $db->loadObjectList();
```

И вывожу на сайте через:

```
foreach($articles as $article) {
    echo $article->introtext;
}
```

Но все выводится НЕ согласно порядку массива $IDs т.е. сначало обьект с ID 5, потом 3 и т.д. а в порядке возрастания ID т.е. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Как сделать чтобы всё выводилось согласно массиву $IDs?

ps. Синтаксис API Joomla

Comment: Можно воспользоваться `ORDER BY FIELD(id, " . implode(',', $IDs) . ")` (не знаю уж как это будет корректно в PHP и Joomla), но вполне возможно (надо проверять), что с точки зрения производительности лучше будет сортировать в PHP-коде.

Comment: А как в РНР-коде отсортировать?

Comment: Сохранить полученные строки в виде хеш-таблицы (наверняка ведь в PHP такое есть), ключом в которой будет выступать ID полученной строки, а значением - сама строка. Затем в цикле пробегаться по `$IDs` и брать соответствующий `article` из хеш-таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел сам похожий вариант, но вроде бы проще:

```
$arrayOfArticles = array();
foreach($articles as $unsortedArticle) {
    $arrayOfArticles[$unsortedArticle->id] = $unsortedArticle;
}
foreach($IDs as $sortedID) {
    $article = $arrayOfArticles[$sortedID];
    echo $article->introtext;
}
```

Comment: Это вот как раз вариант, который я описывал.

Answer (score 1):

Вначале сформировать массив с нужной сортировкой а потом выводить на страницу

```php
// Перестраиваем индексы исходного массива
$IDs = array_merge($IDs);
// Формируем массив из null элементов и длиной исходного массива
$content = array_fill(0, count($IDs), null);
foreach($articles as $article) {
  // заполняем массив в нужном порядке
  $content[array_search($article->id), $IDs] = $article->introtext;
}
// выводим все заполненные значения
foreach($content as $article) {
  if (isset($article))
    echo $article;
}
```